# What's the difference between aws-amplify-react and @aws-amplify/ui-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I saw many docs and places saying to use `aws-amplify-react` but here on the docs to get start with react I saw this package [@aws-amplify/ui-react](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/react#install-amplify-libraries) to use the module `withAuthentication` (which `aws-amplify-react` also has)

What's the difference between them? When should I use `aws-amplify-react` and when should I use `@aws-amplify/ui-react` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like [`aws-amplify-react` is the legacy package](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui-legacy/q/framework/react) name and it was changed to [`@aws-amplify/ui-react` in the current version](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/q/framework/react).

[image: amplify legacy react ui lib documentation page]

So to answer which to use, use `@aws-amplify/ui-react` as mentioned in the [migration section of the documentation.](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react#migration) The documentation is possibly not up to date everywhere.

They have a [migration section](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/46fcf9659b8913bd522167d3a190f5918768694b#notice) in the repository `README.md` file as well:

> For `aws-amplify-react`'s `Authenticator` Component, you will need to
>   import the styles within your app:
>
> ```
> import '@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css';
> ```

But even that file isn't completely up to date since it still refers to the legacy version in the installation section.

It looks like the documentation update is currently in progress, though you could ask for more guidance on the [documentation repository](https://github.com/aws-amplify/docs/issues).

Comment: Thank you. Those docs of amplify are kind of mess for me, sometimes is hard to find something.

Comment: It really is a mess. And to me it looks like the "new" package is less flexible when it comes to building a custom Amplify Auth UI ? Extending React Components to build a own UI is not possible anymore but instead it uses "slots"... is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: @allesklarbeidir I've honestly never used either, I just looked at the documentation to find the answer above.